# Sometime I can't connect to mysql db with node.js while offline until I'm online, other time it just works, why?

Tags: mysql, node.js, phpmyadmin

My node.js program use the mysql module which I use with xampp. Why does it (sometime)require an internet connection to connect to my db in localhost using the mysql node module while other times it works fine while offline? It won't connect to my db which looks fine in phpmyadmin while offline but once I tried while online then it worked for a while offline then it seems to require internet once again. Why?

Comment: I've asked about it in a chatroom but the only thing they told me was to stop working with windows!

Comment: What do you mean by "require an internet connection" exactly - what error are you getting? does some other part of your code, which perhaps is only sometimes used, depending on circumstances, make a call to something on the internet?

Comment: This could be DNS related. If you're not connecting to, say, `127.0.0.1` then you may need to do a DNS lookup, and if you're offline that will fail. What sorts of specific errors do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Behalf on using **'localhost'** as your **host** you should use **'127.0.0.1'**
That Will solve your problem

```
const host='127.0.0.1';
const user='root';
const password='root';
const database='node_db'

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host:host,
  user:user,
  password: password,
  database: database
})
```